# Импорт таблицы с pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, импорт

Делаю курсовую работу на тему импорта и анализа данных с помощью библиотек из различных сред. С питоном до этого была не знакома (изучали шарп). Для примера импорта взяла код с сайта, пытаюсь запустить у себя -

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character.

Много форумов облазила, советы типо "замени \ на \" не котируются. Бедный-несчастный кусочек кода прилагаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] .

Таблица находится в той же папке. Из другой папки тоже пыталась доставать. Надеюсь на вашу помощь =)
Код с обучающей страницы (https://pythonworld.ru/obrabotka-dannyx/pandas-cookbook-1-csv-reading.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 import pandas as pd
 fixed_df = pd.read_csv('‪bikes.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin1',
                  parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True,
                index_col='Date')

  fixed_df
```

Comment: Во-первых, замените изображение текстом. Во-вторых, вы уверены, что bikes.csv имеет кодировку latin1?

Comment: Да, это пример импорта с сайта, откуда я брала информацию. Даже без параметров, ошибка вылезает

Comment: В вопросе должен быть опубликован воспроизводимый код и полный текст возникающей ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже при скачивании файла нарушилась его кодировка.

Попробуйте парсить CSV файл напрямую - по ссылке:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook/master/data/bikes.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=';', encoding="latin1", index_col="Date"
                 parse_dates=["Date"], dayfirst=True)
```

результат:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
            Berri 1  Brébeuf (données non disponibles)  Côte-Sainte-Catherine  ...  Pierre-Dupuy  Rachel1  St-Urbain (données non disponibles)
Date                                                                           ...
2012-01-01       35                                NaN                      0  ...            10       16                                  NaN
2012-01-02       83                                NaN                      1  ...             6       43                                  NaN
2012-01-03      135                                NaN                      2  ...             3       58                                  NaN
2012-01-04      144                                NaN                      1  ...             8       61                                  NaN
2012-01-05      197                                NaN                      2  ...            13       95                                  NaN
2012-01-06      146                                NaN                      0  ...             4       75                                  NaN
2012-01-07       98                                NaN                      2  ...             6       54                                  NaN
...             ...                                ...                    ...  ...           ...      ...                                  ...
2012-10-30     2887                                NaN                   1251  ...           338     2790                                  NaN
2012-10-31     2634                                NaN                   1294  ...           245     2570                                  NaN
2012-11-01     2405                                NaN                   1208  ...           165     2461                                  NaN
2012-11-02     1582                                NaN                    737  ...            97     1888                                  NaN
2012-11-03      844                                NaN                    380  ...           105     1302                                  NaN
2012-11-04      966                                NaN                    446  ...           197     1374                                  NaN
2012-11-05     2247                                NaN                   1170  ...           179     2430                                  NaN

[310 rows x 9 columns]

In [8]: df.columns
Out[8]:
Index(['Berri 1', 'Brébeuf (données non disponibles)', 'Côte-Sainte-Catherine', 'Maisonneuve 1', 'Maisonneuve 2',
       'du Parc', 'Pierre-Dupuy', 'Rachel1', 'St-Urbain (données non disponibles)'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Всё заработало, в самом деле, спасибо!

Comment: @DashaMukhina, пожалуйста :)